# FOSUserBundle Can only login one time

Tags: session, authentication, fosuserbundle

I'am trying to using the FOSUserBundle with Symfony 3.0.9.

After doing the tutorial [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html) I was able to register a user and login with it, yesterday. The problem was that I couldn't login this morning with the same credentials. After a some tests I noticed that it's not possible to login with the user, when I closed the window.

So i have to delete the user from database and create a new one.
Can anybody help me out to fix this problem?
Surely a user should be able to login, logout and close the brwoser without a logout.

My SecurityController.php:

```
class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {

        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render(
            'security/login.html.twig',
            array(
                // last username entered by the user
                'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                'error'         => $error,
            )
        );
    }
}
```

security.yml:

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

At least my user entity in database:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the session was set by /register and my /login never worked.
With the standard FOSUser Login it worked without problems.